# Why doesn't mysql prompt password?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

If I run `mysql -u root` without option `--password`, mysql immediately denies my login.

If I add `--password`, mysql them prompts password, and if I type correctly, I get in.

https://serverfault.com/questions/537582/mysql-without-password-prompt this guy had the same experience.

According to the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password, "If [the password value is] not given, mysql prompts for one."

But what is the mysql behavior if the whole `--password` option is missing? Why doesn't it just ask for password anyway?

**Update for @RolandoMySQLDBA**

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `root`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT USER() How_I_entered_mysql,CURRENT_USER() How_mysqld_allowed_me_to_enter;
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| How_I_entered_mysql | How_mysqld_allowed_me_to_enter |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| root@localhost      | root@%                         |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please long to mysql and run `SHOW GRANTS; SELECT USER() How_I_entered_mysql,CURRENT_USER() How_mysqld_allowed_me_to_enter;`. What is the output ???

Comment: When `--password` is used and the password value is provided then this value is used. When `--password` is used and the password value is NOT provided then password value is prompted. When `--password` is NOT used then server assumes that anonymous login (without the password) is used, and password value is NOT prompted.

Comment: @Akina "When --password is NOT used then server assumes that anonymous login." Fine, I'll take that. Thank you.